# CALLBACK macro (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I've got a function with a signature like this

```
int iV_SetSampleCallback(pDLLSetSample pSampleCallbackFunction)
```

Where `pDLLSetSample` is

```
typedef int (CALLBACK * pDLLSetSample) (struct SampleStruct rawDataSample);
```

I want to pass my member function as callback

```
int sampleCallbackFunction(struct SampleStruct sample);
```

And when I call it like

```
iV_SetSampleCallback(&MainWindow::sampleCallbackFunction);
```

I got an error

```
error: C2664: 'int iV_SetSampleCallback(pDLLSetSample)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__thiscall MainWindow::* )(SampleStruct)' to 'pDLLSetSample'
```

And I can't understand why it happens. What is `CALLBACK` macro is? Where is `__thiscall` came from? How should I correctly pass my callback to this function?

Comment: Call SensoMotoric and tell them that their callback API is broken. Any callback API that doesn't let you pass a `void*` to the called-back function is broken by design. The `pDLLSetSample` should be declared as `typedef int (CALLBACK * pDLLSetSample)(struct SampleStruct rawDataSample, void * userData)` and also `int iV_SetSampleCallback(pDLLSetSample pSampleCallbackFunction, void * userData)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is occurring because you are trying to pass a pointer to a non-static class member function `sampleCallbackFunction` instead of a pointer to a regular function. Note that non-static class member functions have explicit `this` parameter. `CALLBACK`  macro is often used in Windows and typically stands for `stdcall` calling convention.

To fix this error you need to

- declare member callback function as static
- prepend CALLBACK macro to member function so it will have expected calling convention (or whatever CALLBACK expands to)

```c++
static int CALLBACK sampleCallbackFunction(struct SampleStruct sample);
```

Comment: Typically API provides a way to pass some opaque pointer-like parameter that will later be passed into callback. But in your case there is no such parameter for some reason so your only choice is store this pointer in some global variable before installing callback.