# How to set a function callback to a private function of a class?

Tags: c++, windows

I need to set function as a callback for a function that is provided by an API. Now the API provides an example that allowed me to write this code and it works:
In the header file:

```
#include <iostream>    

int __stdcall newDataAvailable(SampleStruct datum);
class Interface:

public:

    Interface();

    // Connects to the local server. Returns false if it fails.
    bool connectToServer();

private:


};
```

And in the implementation I have:

```
Interface::Interface()
{
    iV_SetSampleCallback(newDataAvailable);
}

bool Interface::connectToServer(){

// code to connect to server
}

int __stdcall newDataAvailable(SampleStruct datum){
    std::cout << "New DATA" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So, so far so good. Now the problem comes when I want to make the function newDataAvailable part of the class. So I copy the header into the private area of the class declaraion, add an Interface:: in the implemetation cpp file and try agai.

However I do not know how to make the connection, as it fails to compile. This is what I've tried:

```
iV_SetSampleCallback(&newDataAvailable); // Gives me illegal & operation
iV_SetSampleCallback(Interface::newDataAvailable);  // error: C3867: 'Interface::newDataAvailable': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
iV_SetSampleCallback(&Interface::newDataAvailable); // error: C2664: 'int iV_SetSampleCallback(pDLLSetSample)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__stdcall Interface::* )(SampleStruct)' to 'pDLLSetSample'
iV_SetSampleCallback(newDataAvailable); // error: C3867: 'Interface::newDataAvailable': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

So what is the proper way to set the callback?

Comment: So what does the *real* code look like? That header is obviously not real code.

Comment: I believe that your function would have to have parameters of 'Interface' type...did you accomplish that?  where?  What you show here can't be complete...

Comment: I don't understand your remarks. This is the real code. The last four attempts simply replace the line in the constructor,

Answer (score 2):

This message:

```
iV_SetSampleCallback(&Interface::newDataAvailable); // error: C2664: 'int iV_SetSampleCallback(pDLLSetSample)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int (__stdcall Interface::* )(SampleStruct)' to 'pDLLSetSample'
```

Says the type is wrong. The syntax is, in fact, 'correct', you're just not doing what you think you were doing. What you were actually doing is pass a pointer to a member function which uses a `Interface*` as `this` type, but the API wants pointers to functions (that are not bound to particular object instances) which is why you get the type error instead.

Note that your type brings up this ask: [CALLBACK macro (QT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43392246/callback-macro-qt)
If that is the case for you as well, it looks like you are going to have to use a global variable (may be dressed up as a singleton) because of piss poor API design on 'their' part.

Comment: Thanks!! It seems some asked my exact same question before!! It seems like there is no way I can do what I want without having to use static functions, though. That is a bummer.

Comment: @aarelovich You're stuck with a free function or static method in there somewhere, but if you have only one instance of `Interface`, a static method can turn around and call a private method if you have a that single instance reference available somewhere. If you have more than one instance, you have a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've figured. I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1):

You can add `newDataAvailable` function has part of class by declaring it as static. Once that function has been declared static then you can use it as part of callback function. Not sure if that is your intention.

Comment: You can think of having a Singleton class design where it got instance of class stored in a member. In those situations you can use static member function of class and set that as callback.

Comment: Slapping `static` on it defeats the purpose of having it as a member function.